# List items partially overlapping each other most of the times

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

On tap handler of a panel I am creating a list(which uses itemTpl), then populating its store with relevant items and then setting it to the container. When this list is shown first item is shown fully and rest all other items below it, overlap each other. This happens 90% of the time not always and if I resize browser or change orientation of device overlapping disappears and all items look proper.

Here is my store:

```
var listStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id','image','name','description']
});
```

Here is how I am populating the store:

```
var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
var arr = json.categories;
for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    if(arr[x].id == self.parent.cid){
        var itemsArr = arr[x].items;
        var myitems = [];
        for(var y = 0; y < itemsArr.length; y++) {
            myitems.push({"id":itemsArr[y].id, "image":itemsArr[y].image, "name":itemsArr[y].name, "description":itemsArr[y].description});
        }
        listStore.add(myitems);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am creating the list:

```
var itemsList = {
    xtype: 'list',
    itemTpl : self.parent.tp,
    store : listStore,
    flex : 1,
    id : 'ilid',
    layout : 'fit',
    templateId : 'detailsTemplate_'+self.parent.cid,
    detailsView : 'myshop.view.'+self.parent.ctype+'Details',
    direction: 'vertical',
    listeners: {
      itemtap: function (list, index, element, record)
      {
            var popup = Ext.create(list.detailsView, {
                    rec : record.getData(),
                    tid : list.templateId
            });
            Ext.Viewport.add(popup);
            popup.show('pop');
      }
    }
};
```

Here is template:

```
<tpl for="."><div class="tp_1"><div class="productBox"><div class="productTitle">{name}</div><div class="productBody"><img class="productImage" src="{image}"/></div></div></div></tpl>
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Overlapping list items]

Please help!

EDIT!!!
Here is Template:

```
<tpl for=".">
    <div class="tp_5">
        <div class="productBox">
            <div class="productTitle">{name}</div>
            <div class="productBody"><img class="productImage" src="{image}" width="300"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</tpl>
```

and here is related CSS:

```
.productBox
    {
        border:1px solid #9a9a9a;
    }
.productTitle
    {
        border-bottom:1px solid #9a9a9a;
        padding:5px 10px 0px 10px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size: 80%;
        height:30px;
    }
.productBody
    {
        padding:10px;
        background-color: white;
    }
.productImage
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
    }
.tp_5 .productBody, .st_5 {
        background-color : white;
    }
```

**Edit**

While testing various thing like using flex, providing margins, doing refresh etc I realized that this overlap happens only when the list is loaded for the first time. When I go back to main page and remove it from container

```
hccontainer.remove(Ext.getCmp('ilid'), true);
```

and then again create and put it in container onTap event, it renders fine.

Also overlapping happens only second item onwards, first item is always shown fully.

Comment: Also show us the CSS for the HTML in your template.

Comment: Hey TDeBailleul, I have added template and CSS. Also thanks for reminding me to accept some outstanding answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cleaner workaround for this issue by providing height to template div which holds image.

```
    .productBody
    {
        padding:10px;
        background-color: white;
        height : 240px;
    }
```

Looks like overlapping was happening because there was no default CSS height for template.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an open issue with Sencha:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?249938-List-Items-with-height-gt-47px-not-rendered-correctly.

The workaround which worked in my case was to do deferred refresh of list like this:

```
var l = Ext.getCmp('ilid');
Ext.defer(function(){ 
  l.refresh(); 
  console.log("Refreshed");
}, 100, l);
```

Hoping to see TOUCH-3781 fixed very soon.

Comment: Quick update on the status of that bug to save people trawling through the entire thread. As of today (28th May 2013) it is still open but a couple of workarounds have been proposed: 1. Give your image elements in the template a fixed height (it seems list item positions are not recalculated after the resource has loaded and settled on its real height). 2. In 'painted' event perform a deferred refresh - Ext.defer(function(){ this.refresh(); }, 50, this);. Credit to those in that thread for the workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'div' in your template in Sencha Touch 2.2.1 brings overlap for me. My workaround has been to convert the 'div' to an html table, so your template would become:

```
<table><tr><td>{name}</td>
<tr><td><img class="productImage" src="{image}" width="300"></td></tr></table>
```